# Bash syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax

Forgive me for this is a very simple script in Bash. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# june 2011

if [ $# -lt 3 -o $# -gt 3 ]; then
   echo "Error... Usage: $0 host database username"
   exit 0
fi
```

after running sh file.sh:

> syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I think file.sh is with CRLF line terminators.

run

```
dos2unix file.sh
```

then the problem will be fixed.

You can install dos2unix in ubuntu with this:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: Whats the reason behind this problem? I usually work on Windows but need to transfer scripts to unix systems.

Comment: Newline in windows is "\r\n", while in linux is "\n".

Comment: @KeesdeKooter I wouldn't say just because something didn't work for you that you should downvote it, clearly it worked for the 28 upvotes.  A simple it didn't work for me suffices.  That's why SO allowed multiple answers to a question because there can be multiple solutions to a problem.

Comment: Using notepad++ editor Edit>EOL Conversion>Old Mac Format solved it for me.

Comment: If you can Edit your bash file with Notepad++. Go to Edit-> EOL Conversion-> Macintosh(CR). Change it to Macintosh(CR) even if you are using Windows OS.

Comment: Before installing maybe try (in vim) ':set fileformat=unix'. This worked for me in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai — the problem arises because Bash treats `then\r` as a command name, and `fi\r` as another, and then thinks that it has not seen the correct format for an `if …; then …; fi` statement — so it reports 'unexpected EOF'.

Answer (score 183):

Another thing to check (just occured to me):

- **terminate bodies of single-line functions with semicolon**

I.e. this innocent-looking snippet will cause the same error:

```
die () { test -n "$@" && echo "$@"; exit 1 }
```

To make the dumb parser happy:

```
die () { test -n "$@" && echo "$@"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: +1 Also applies to code snippets with brackets like so: [[ "$#" == 1 ]] && [[ "$arg" == [1,2,3,4] ]] 
        && printf "%s\n" "blah"  || { printf "%s\n" "blahblah"; usage; }    ............ Note that semicolon inside the squiggly brackets, just after calling some previously defined function 'usage'. Forgetting that will get you the same syntax error: unexpected eof.

Comment: you nailed it. Actually the simple thing is the `;` Every statement is being expected to end with `;` so put that at the end eg: `if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then . ~/.git-completion.bash fi` will produce that error, whereas `if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then . ~/.git-completion.bash; fi;` will not... notice the little semi-colons at the end, ie: after `.bash` and `fi`.

Comment: I had this  in a script shared with me from a `zsh` user. The former does work in `zsh` but not in `sh` nor `bash`. Wish I was 4 people so I could give this 4 upvotes

Answer (score 76):

i also just got this error message by using the wrong syntax in an `if` clause

- `else if` (syntax error: unexpected end of file)
- `elif` (correct syntax)

i debugged it by commenting bits out until it worked

Comment: Thank you soo much.. someone please give this guy a medal

Answer (score 38):

an un-closed if => fi clause will raise this as well

tip: use trap to debug, if your script is huge...

e.g.

```
set -x
trap read debug
```

Comment: I exactly forgot the "fi"! Thanks :) If you could, for the benefit of everyone, elaborate a bit on your tip of using trap.

Comment: sorry for the delay, my friend.  'the 'trap' command is a way to debug your scripts by esentially breaking after every line.  a fuller discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080431/how-execute-bash-script-line-by-line

Comment: That was useful thanks a lot. Note that the `unexpected end of file` error will occur as soon as the `fi` is hit.

Comment: Ah so, one should not write those set and trap commands into the actual script, as it says in that post you suggested might clarify your answer? You write it in the shell, and then call the script. Please do clarify, save everyone running round in circles.

Comment: @Markling - I anticipate folks would take the traps out after they have debugged their script.

Comment: That is, if they are advised well enough that they know what a trap is, and where and how they should put it!

Answer (score 17):

I got this answer from [this similar problem on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929705/bashrc-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

Open the file in Vim and try

`:set fileformat=unix`

> Convert eh line endings to unix endings and see if that solves the
>   issue. If editing in Vim, enter the command :set fileformat=unix and
>   save the file. Several other editors have the ability to convert line
>   endings, such as Notepad++ or Atom

Thanks @lemongrassnginger

Comment: These are just alternative ways to do `dos2unix` as the accepted answer advises.

Answer (score 13):

I had the problem when I wrote "if - fi" statement in one line:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then . ~/.git-completion.bash fi
```

Write multiline solved my problem:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then 
    . ~/.git-completion.bash
 fi
```

Comment: You can also keep it as one line like this: `if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then . ~/.git-completion.bash; fi` (note the `;` near the end).

Answer (score 12):

This was happening for me when I was trying to call a function using parens, e.g.

```
run() {
  echo hello
}

run()
```

should be:

```
run() {
  echo hello
}

run
```

Comment: Thank you!! It was just my problem, I thought it was related to the other answers.

Answer (score 8):

So I found this post and the answers did not help me but i was able to figure out why it gave me the error. I had a

```
cat > temp.txt < EOF
some content
EOF
```

The issue was that i copied the above code to be in a function and inadvertently tabbed the code. Need to make sure the last EOF is not tabbed.

Comment: This was exactly my case. I had `EOF` indented by four spaces and bash didn't parse it because of that. Removing spaces fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

on cygwin I needed:-

```
 export SHELLOPTS
 set -o igncr
```

in .bash_profile . This way I didn't need to run unix2dos

Answer (score 5):

**FOR WINDOWS:**

In my case, I was working on Windows OS and I got the same error while running autoconf.

- I simply open configure.ac file with my **NOTEPAD++** IDE.
- Then I converted the File with **EOL** conversion into **Windows (CR LF)** as follows:

  **EDIT -> EOL CONVERSION -> WINDOWS (CR LF)**

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me. I use OpenShift s2i nginx

Answer (score 4):

Missing a closing brace on a function definition will cause this error as I just discovered.

```
function whoIsAnIidiot() {
    echo "you are for forgetting the closing brace just below this line !"
```

Which of course should be like this...

```
function whoIsAnIidiot() {
    echo "not you for sure"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### For those who don't have *dos2unix* installed (and don't want to install it):

Remove trailing `\r` character that causes this error:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' filename
```

Details from this StackOverflow answer. This was really helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32912867/7286223

Answer (score 2):

I was able to cut and paste your code into a file and it ran correctly.  If you
execute it like this it should work:

Your "file.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
# june 2011

if [ $# -lt 3 -o $# -gt 3 ]; then
   echo "Error... Usage: $0 host database username"
   exit 0
fi
```

The command:

```
$ ./file.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Note that "file.sh" must be executable:

```
$ chmod +x file.sh
```

You may be getting that error b/c of how you're doing input (w/ a pipe, carrot,
etc.).  You could also try splitting the condition into two:

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ] || [ $# -gt 3 ]; then
   echo "Error... Usage: $0 host database username"
   exit 0
fi
```

Or, since you're using `bash`, you could use built-in syntax:

```
if [[ $# -lt 3 || $# -gt 3 ]]; then
   echo "Error... Usage: $0 host database username"
   exit 0
fi
```

And, finally, you could of course just check if 3 arguments were given (clean,
maintains POSIX shell compatibility):

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
   echo "Error... Usage: $0 host database username"
   exit 0
fi
```

Comment: i still got the same error. im not exactly sure where the code goes wrong

Comment: weird, i cut and pasted your code and it worked as expected.  was there any more error output? a lot of time bash will list a line number.  also, what system are you running? (Linux, MacOS, BSD, distro, etc)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there is a redundant `\` in the like following:

```
function foo() {
    python tools/run_net.py \
                           --cfg configs/Kinetics/X3D_8x8_R50.yaml \
                           NUM_GPUS 1 \
                           TRAIN.BATCH_SIZE 8 \
                           SOLVER.BASE_LR 0.0125 \
                           DATA.PATH_TO_DATA_DIR ./afs/kinetics400 \
                           DATA.PATH_PREFIX  ./afs/kinetics400  \  # Error
}
```

There is **NOT** a `\` at the end of `DATA.PATH_PREFIX  ./afs/kinetics400`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, some versions of the shell can also emit this message when the final line of your script lacks a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I just cut-and-pasted your example into a file; it ran fine under bash.  I don't see any problems with it.

For good measure you may want to ensure it ends with a newline, though bash shouldn't care.  (It runs for me both with and without the final newline.)

You'll sometimes see strange errors if you've accidentally embedded a control character in the file.  Since it's a short script, try creating a new script by pasting it from your question here on StackOverflow, or by simply re-typing it.

What version of bash are you using?  (`bash --version`)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the directory in which the .sh file is present does not have a space character. e.g: Say if it is in a folder called 'New Folder', you're bound to come across the error that you've cited. Instead just name it as 'New_Folder'. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu:

```
$ gedit ~/.profile
```

Then, `File -> Save as` and set `end line` to `Unix/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late to the party. Hope this may help someone.

Check your .bashrc file. Perhaps rename or move it.

Discussion here: [Unable to source a simple bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720897/unable-to-source-a-simple-bash-script/55751299?noredirect=1#comment98182583_55751299)

Answer (score 0):

For people using MacOS:

If you received a file with Windows format and wanted to run on MacOS and seeing this error, run these commands.

```
brew install dos2unix
sh <file.sh>
```

Comment: this seems to me like installing dos2unix utility then not using it

Comment: dos2unix is used internally when you run sh to parse the .sh file.

Comment: oh wow, by what? Does Homebrew wrap sh with a dos2unix piping wrapper script?

Comment: I'll dare to say by pure guess that Homebrew doesn't do it. Moreover, if it does, it'd be good not to rely on that.

Comment: Also, Homebrew is not preinstalled out of the box on macOS last time I heard, so it's important to note that

Answer (score 0):

*If* the the script itself is valid and there are no syntax errors, then some possible causes could be:

- Invalid end-of-lines (for example, `\r\n` instead of `\n`)
- Presence of the `byte order mark` ([BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the beginning of the file

Both can be fixed using `vim` or `vi`.

To fix line endings open the file in vim and from the command mode type:

```
:set ff=unix
```

To remove the BOM use:

```
:set nobomb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **vscode** you can create a .editorconfig file and put this in it:

```
[*.sh]
end_of_line = cr
```

then save your bash files again,
as far as I understood when you save a file vscode by default uses `crlf` as end of line to present line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I found @Juniar 's answer very helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693268/5838310

Mine was originally set as Windows(CR LF) and reported error; when I changed it to Unix (LF), it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem comes from EOL in differences OS EOL**

I resolve this problem with below steps

Step 1: If you using Notepad++ in windows please add end line at end of file (*) with Enter keyboard

Step 2: In Notepad++ Edit> EOL conversion -> Unix (LF)

Step 3: Save the file with any named you want (exp: test.sh), after that using the file in Unix OS

Step 4: Running the basg file with command "bash test.sh"

Thank you @tensom for your answer

```
echo  "###  ABC START  ###"
pid= "abc"
if [ ${pid} != "" ]
then
  echo "a running"
else
  echo "a not running"
fi (*)
```