# Is there an editor that allows to evaluate the current line as a bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, editor, eval

I'd like to evaluate a bash script line by line. I also might want to jump back and execute a previous line again.

As described in [How execute bash script line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080431/how-execute-bash-script-line-by-line) , one could use the built-in debugging option `-x`, but this is not very handy, since you don't have the overview of previous and future commands.

For writing software in R, I used [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/). The editor allows to evaluate the current line as an R-Command by hitting `Ctrl`+`Enter`. Afterwards the result is shown in a built-in shell, and the Cursor jumps to the next command.

Is there a simple text-editor (like gedit) that allows to send the current line to a built-in shell/console (bash, zsh,...) and view the result of the evlauation afterwards in the shell?

Comment: In Emacs, you can easily add such a function to the editor, if it's not already there.

Comment: How? (I went through all menus, but could not find anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with the editor [geany](http://geany.org). In their Wiki they have a [detailed instruction](http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/using_geany_with_r). In short:

- Install geany
- Open the file `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` and set `send_selection_unsafe=true`
- Restart geany
- Set a key-binding `Edit > Preferences > Keybindings` (It is under `Format / Send selection to terminal`)

Actually you don't have to select the code you want to send. So far I couldn't find out how to instruct geany to jump to the next line afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

It's not built in to Emacs, but it's easy to do.

```
(defun shell-eval-line (pos)
  "Evaluate the line around position as a shell command.
In interactive mode, use the cursor's position."
  (interactive "d")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char pos)
    (shell-command (buffer-substring
            (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))) ))
```

Bind to a key of your liking (`C-c !` maybe?) and go.

Add a `(next-line)` outside the `(save-excursion)` to make it advance to the next line when it's done, or create a simple macro around it to invoke the function and jump to the next line.

Comment: Typically, in your `$HOME/.emacs.d/init.el` file.  If you only want to load it when you need it, and not burden your `init.el` with stuff you rarely use, put it in a separate file and load it from there.  For quick ad-hoc experimentation, just paste it in the `*scratch*` buffer and `M-x eval-defun`  See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile.