# .bashrc syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash

I am getting an unexpected end of file error. I am not really sure how to fix it.

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

export PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;32m\]\$\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;37m\]'

export LS_COLORS='di=35;1'


alias la='ls -lah'
alias cdu='cd /home/hzhang/primary'

#module load gnu-compilers/4.7.0
#module load mvapich3/gnu/1.7

.ls /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/072/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64

#PATH=$PATH:/home/hzhang/primary/over2.2e/bin_dp:/home/hzhang/primary/foiltest
PATH=$PATH:/opt/overflow/intel/serial/bin_dp/:/home/hzhang/primary/chimera2.1/bin_dp/:/u/primary/hzhang/pegasus/bin_dp
export PATH

ulimit -s unlimited
```

Comment: Nothing apparent in that file, though `.ls` looks odd. Check `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: ... and assuming the `.ls` is typo only here, in the question, check the `.../ifortvars.sh` too. And you might want to enclose `$PATH` in double quotes, in case a PATH element contains some special characters (like brackets).

Comment: as @tooboring4me mentions check if all lines including the last end in `\n`

Comment: // , .bashrc loads several other files, like .bash_aliases. Check here for an example of this error that was fixed by editing another file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211571/bashrc-error-bash-home-jason-bashrc-line-115-syntax-error-unexpected-end

Answer (score 20):

I had the same error due to missing "fi" line. Make sure to omit syntax errors. 
The original .bashrc is located in /etc/skel/. So just run the following command:

cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~

Answer (score 11):

I was facing a similar problem. Using the bash that comes with Windows 10, somehow the line endings had been changed to windows line endings (CRLF). Changing the file back to use unix line endings solved the issue.

Convert eh line endings to unix endings and see if that solves the issue. If editing in Vim, enter the command `:set fileformat=unix` and save the file. Several other editors have the ability to convert line endings, such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. It has worked for me. I have cross-posted your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file/49226909#49226909. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: This was the solution for me.  Very good observations and suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Such syntax errors are really simple to find. At first glance the file looks okay, so I'd suggest you comment out every single line (with `#`) and see if the error still manifests.

Then just do binary search, that is, comment in the first half of the file. If that works continue with the third quarter (otherwise with the first quarter). And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, it turned out to be a missing "}" at the end of a function. I made a backup of the faulty one (in order to have an idea of what my setup was) and then copied the original fine (cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~) and added the lines again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because i made some changes in my .bashcr file and messed up the terminal. Follow command fixed my issue:

```
ecp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Answer (score 0):

This .bashrc shall have been edited from windows.
fromdos .bashrcé to correct this file in order to source it.

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed information, coz only a few would understand this...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the topic.

Instead of commenting out the entire file or copying and restoring it, you can just do a diff:

```
$ diff .bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

If it is something simple, you will quickly see it.

I just had the same problem. I'd commented out a `fi` and did not notice it.

Answer (score -1):

Just open the file from terminal by `gedit .bashrc` 
The document will open ,go to the bottom and see if `fi` is missing there,if it is not there add it.Just put "fi" at the left margin at the last and close all the commands with "fi".[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FAng.png)

Answer (score -3):

.
.
.
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
**Fi**
In the first line of my terminal i got **There is error at the end of the /.bashrc file** but when i change **Fi** to **fi** it works fine like

.
.
.
.
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
**fi**

Comment: Could you please add the code in a code block. It increases the readability.