# .bashrc error bash: /home/jason/.bashrc: line 115: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

Here is the error that appears at the top of the screen when I start a new terminal:

> bash: /home/jason/.bashrc: line 115: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I went to said file and and tried commenting out the following lines (The final line of this code is line 115.) of code which solved the problem in a very sloppy way:

```
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  #if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    #. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  #elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    #. /etc/bash_completion
  #fi
#fi
```

I am not familiar with this code, and would appreciate a solution, or even a suggestion on how to format this question better.

Comment: Are any of those lines line 115? It's hard to tell what the actual problem is, because it's likely to be somewhere else in the script.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a little context, a few lines before and after what you commented out, and showing how you commented it out. The error potentially means that a block was not closed off before the end of file was reached (*e.g.*, an `if` without a `fi`). The code snippet you show appears to be proper syntax for a complete `if` block.

Comment: Thank you for your input I will redit accordingly.

Comment: // , Is this a question? I am failing to notice the part where this post. *asks.* *a.* **question.**

Comment: When I ask for a solution, it is implied that I want a solution that doesn't involve just commenting out possibly necessary code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when I went into my .bash_aliases file and commented out piece by piece my aliases the following alias was the culprit.

```
alias fi='firefox'
```

The reason this is faulty is because fi is the end of an if statement, and the way this went into bash script it was read as ending the if, rather than as the name of the desired alias. Resulting in a error.

Her is the fixed line.

```
alias fir='firefox'
```

Moral of the story is don't use fi as an alias because it is read as the end to an if statement in bash script.

Comment: // , Why would an error in the .bash_aliases file present as an error in *line 115 of .bashrc*? I'm seriously impressed that you somehow managed to find this, but still... Wow.

Comment: The reason it presented itself as an error in line 115 is because it added an extra fi at an earlier part of the bash file where it references the .bash_alias file. Thus when reaching the end of the program it realized there were more fi that if and gave the error mentioned in the question.