# System command in perl

Tags: perl, bash

I need to run a system command which would go to a directory and delete sub directories excluding files if present. I wrote the below command to perform this operation:

```
system("cd /home/faizan/test/cache ; for i in *\; do if [ -d \"$i\" ]\; then echo \$i fi done");
```

The command above keeps throwing syntax error. I have tried multiple combinations but still not clear how this should go. Please suggest.

Comment: error: sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Why not create a bash file separately and then call it from your Perl program?

Comment: This particular command needs to be executed on around 16 servers through ssh/perl. I need some way to perform this operation using a single perl script on multiple servers

Comment: You might be facing [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

Comment: Tried above but still the same error message. Somehow I feel that it is related to the way the command has been formed but I am not able to pinpoint the mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your command line does contain syntax errors. Try this:

```
system("cd /home/faizan/test/cache ; for i in *; do if [ -d \"\$i\" ]; then echo \$i; fi; done");
```

Or better yet, only loop over directories in the first place;

```
system("for i in /home/faizan/test/cache/*/.; do echo \$i; done");
```

Or better yet, do it without a loop:

```
system("echo /home/faizan/test/cache/*/.");
```

(I suppose you will want to `rmdir` instead of `echo` once it is properly debugged.)

Or better yet, do it all in Perl. There is nothing here which requires `system()`.

Comment: Thank you..your suggestion worked..I will try to implement this in perl

Answer (score 1):

As question title stand for `system` command, this will answer directly, but the sample command using bash contain only thing that will be simplier in perl only (take a look at other answer using `opendir` and `-d` in perl).

If you want to use `system` (instead of `open $cmdHandle,"bash -c ... |"`), the prefered syntax for execution commands like `system` or `exec`, is to let `perl` parsing the command line.

Try this (as you've already done):

```
perl -e 'system("bash -c \"echo hello world\"")'
hello world

perl -e 'system "bash -c \"echo hello world\"";'
hello world
```

And now better, same but letting `perl` ensure command line parsing, try this:

```
perl -e 'system "bash","-c","echo hello world";'
hello world
```

There are clearly 3 argument of `system` command:

1. bash
2. -c
3. the script

or little more:

```
perl -e 'system "bash","-c","echo hello world;date +\"Now it is %T\";";'
hello world
Now it is 11:43:44
```

as you can see in last purpose, there is no double *double-quotes* enclosing *bash script* part of command line.

**Nota: on command line, using `perl -e '...'` or `perl -e "..."`, it's a little heavy to play with quotes and double-quotes. In a script, you could mix them:

```
system 'bash','-c','for ((i=10;i--;));do printf "Number: %2d\n" $i;done';
```

or even:

```
system 'bash','-c','for ((i=10;i--;));do'."\n".
                       'printf "Number: %2d\n" $i'."\n".
                       'done';
```

Using dots `.` for *concatening* part of (script part) string, there are always 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You're still best off trying this as a bash command first. Formatting that properly makes it much clearer that you're missing statement terminators:

```bsh
for i in *; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

And condensing that by replacing new lines with semicolons (apart from after `do`/`then`):

```bsh
for i in *; do if [ -d "$i" ]; then echo $i; fi; done
```

Or as has been mentioned, just do it in Perl (I haven't tested this to the point of actually uncommenting remove_tree - be careful!):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path 'remove_tree';
use feature 'say';

chdir '/tmp';
opendir my $cache, '.';
while (my $item = readdir($cache)) {
    if ($item !~ /^\.\.?$/ && -d $item) {
        say "Deleting '$item'...";
        # remove_tree($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. The problem is that only one server has perl installed and others dont where this has to be executed. I need to ssh to those servers using perl and then execute either a sh script or something similar to above.

Answer (score 1):

**Using system**

```
my @args = ("cd /home/faizan/test/cache ; for i in *; do if [ -d \"\$i\" ]; then echo \$i; fi; done");
system(@args);
```

**Using Subroutine**

```
sub do_stuff {
  my @args = ( "bash", "-c", shift );
  system(@args);
}

do_stuff("cd /home/faizan/test/cache ; for i in *; do if [ -d \"\$i\" ]; then echo \$i; fi; done");
```