# Why do I have end of file error here?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

This is a linux script shell and I am running it on Ubuntu 13.1
I get a `line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when I run the script. 
here is my script:

```
!#/bin/bash
x=$(stat --printf="%a\n" hi1.txt)
y=$(stat --printf="%a\n" hi1copy.txt)
echo "$x"
echo "$y"
if [ "$x" == "$y" ]; then
  echo "same la!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it with the dos2unix cmd.

```
dos2unix yourfile.sh
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file).

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
!#/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```