# Shell script - multiline statements work from command line (PuTTy) but not from script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, multiline

(I apologize in advance: I don't know whether my problem concerns rather the code syntax or the file system and would - in the latter case -rather fit into a Linux forum)

I'm trying to set up a litte shell script. But as soon as it comes to multiline statements, I came across a strange behaviour.

It took the example blow from a tutorial page:

```
number=1
if [ $number = "1" ]; then
    echo "Number equals 1"
else
    echo "Number does not equal 1"
fi
```

That works fine if I connect via PuTTy to my virtual linux machine (openSUSE 13.1) and copy&paste the code. It does what is expected.

But when I create a file named shell_test.sh (connected via SFTP Net Drive) containing the content below

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1
if [ $number = "1" ]; then
    echo "Number equals 1"
else
    echo "Number does not equal 1"
fi
```

and call it from the command line with `bash shell_test.sh` I get an error:

> line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

The same happens with a for loop. The syntax error is then near the token "do".

Comment: For number comparisons, do not use `=` but `-eq`. See http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/comparison-ops.html for more info.

Comment: try -eq option like,if [ $number -eq 1 ]; then

Comment: In any case, the script works for me with GNU bash Version 4.3.11 as it is without any error.

Comment: One question, did you create the file under windows? I suspect a wrong line encoding. Try `dos2unix shell_test.sh` and then `bash shell_test.sh`

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give to @martin.

Comment: @martin. Yes, I did create the file under windows and that was obviously the problem. Re-creating the file with vi solved the problem (do2unix is not available on my system). I suspected something like this but didn't find the solution myself.

Comment: @cis, this will get you every time. Download **notepad++** for windows and you can set the end-of-line completion to **Unix** and eliminate the problem (`notepad++` is probably the best editor for you on the windows side)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash syntax error: unexpected end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)