# Makefile remove stopped Docker containers

Tags: makefile

I'm new to Makefiles, I'm trying to use one to help me automate the build of my docker images.

I'm struggling to write, what feels like, a simple recipe that does the following:

- Check to see if there are running containers (`docker ps -a -q`)
- If running containers exist remove them (`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`)

This is what I've manage to cobble together so far through various Google searches:

```sh
DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST := $(shell docker ps -a -q)

clean-docker:
    if [[ ! $(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST) == "" ]];then \ 
        docker rm $$(docker ps -a -q) \ 
    fi
```

Which yields the following output:

> if [[ de6e694da4f9 == "" ]];then \
>   /bin/sh: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
>   /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near 'de6e694da4f9'
>   /bin/sh: -c: line 0: 'if [[ de6e694da4f9 == "" ]];then \ '
>   make: *** [clean-docker] Error 2

Would be great if someone could show me how to achieve this please

**UPDATE**

Thank @I0b0 for your answer, I think I'm almost there now.  The `Makefile` now looks like this:

```sh
DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST := $(shell docker ps -a -q)

clean-docker:
    if [ -n "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" ] \
    then \
        docker rm "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" \
    fi
```

But I get the following error when running it:

> if [ -n "6778d35e5c95" ] \
>           then \
>                   docker rm "6778d35e5c95" \
>           fi
>   /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   make: *** [clean-docker] Error 1

I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file) regarding line endings, but that made no difference.  I am using `Makefile` on both Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with:

```
# for images
docker rmi $(shell docker images -a -q)

# for containers
docker rm $(shell docker ps -a -q)

# for volumes
docker volume rm $(shell docker volume ls -q)
```

PS. macOS

Answer (score 0):

`if [ -n "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" ]` should do it:

- `-n` is the standard test for a non-empty string
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) never gets old
- [`[[` is a bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Conditionals), but [`sh` is not `bash`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts)

Bonus points for reusing the variable with `docker rm "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)"`.

---

After the update the problem is related to a fundamental difference between scripts and makefiles: the latter cannot be broken into lines in the exact same way as scripts by just adding backslashes before the end of line. What you've ended up with is a single line `if [ -n "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" ] then    docker rm "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" fi`. Because newlines in a makefile don't work like `;` in a shell script you have to add two:

```
if [ -n "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" ]; \
then \
    docker rm "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)"; \
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @I0b0, that's almost done it, but I'm now struggling with an `unexpected end of file` error.  I've added some more info to the question, don't suppose you know why that might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to divide those commands into multiple lines either, but ugly oneliners work for me.

So what you were asking about would be something like this

```
DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST := $(shell docker ps -a -q)

clean_docker:
    @if [ -n "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)" ]; then echo "Removing docker containers" && docker rm "$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_LIST)"; else echo "No containers found"; fi;
```